# Database design for user packages and credit system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am working on web application in which user can purchase packages. On the base of these packages user can do different operations. Currently I am using following structure.

[image]

My Questions Are.

1. Is this database design is correct
2. Now i want user can upgrade his package

> (Startup --> Premium or Professional)
>
> (Premium --> Professional)

Where these package priority should be saved?

My thought. I have to create new table ( PackagePriority ) with following structure

> PriorityId (PK) - PackageId (FK) - PriorPackage  (this will also
> PackageId with different name)
>
> 1 (PK) - 1 (FK) - 2 (FK)
>
> 2 (PK) - 1 (FK) - 3 (FK)
>
> 3 (PK) - 2 (FK) - 3 (FK)

is this right idea?

How can i find user current package is upgradeable to other packages?

Comment: How does the cost of the priority affect the invoiced amount? Also is it not better to name userpayments as UserInvoice? - Payments are different from an invoice.

Comment: @EmmadKareem First when user want to purchase any package then all packages are listed so he select any one package. if user selected package is Startup then he can upgrade his package. so when user logged in and i got user current package is Startup now i want to show user can upgrade to other packages. but how can i decide these scenario dynamically mean on run time